# Is it possible to change the size of a container at a breakpoint with Bootstrap 5 through class name

Tags: css, bootstrap-5

I have a div which I am styling with bootstrap 5.
I want this container to have width 50 when the screen is bigger than the medium breakpoint, and it should have width 75 as defualt.
With tailwind, I have used something like `md:w-50`. But I am not able to find something similar with bootstrap. Is it possible to change the size with the class name?
I have been able to alter padding in this manner but not width of the container for some reason.
What I tried in the div tag was `w-md-50`, but it did not work.

```
<div class="container-sm w-75 min-vh-75 d-flex flex-column justify-content-lg-start align-items-center m-auto mt-3">
    <p></p>
</div>
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In bootstrap 5, since responsiveness of the `width` class is not set as default, you need to enable it before use it. Please checkout the documentation [Enable responsive](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.0/utilities/api/#enable-responsive).

To activate the width responsive class, you can do this:

```
$utilities: map-merge(
  $utilities, (
    "width": map-merge(
      map-get($utilities, "width"),
      ( responsive: true ),
    ),
  )
);
```